# Something went wrong initializing the native ReactNativeLocalization module

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have an app that was developed for iOS and now I want to make it work on Android too. Thus far I managed to tackle all the issues but I've been stuck on this one for a while. Here is the error:

[image]

React Native version is 0.62.2. I cleared `node_modules`, ran `npm install`, rebuilt the gradle dependencies, still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more hours I managed to solve it. I ran `rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm i`, after than in `android/` I ran `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build`. After that I ran `react-native link react-native-localization`. After that the `ReactNativeLocalizationPackage` cound't be found so I added in `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':react-native-localization'
project(':react-native-localization').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-localization/android')
```